# Save Woocommerce cart item custom data as order item meta data displaying it on orders and emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Regarding Woocommerce. I have custom data that I am adding to the cart. In the functions.php file, I have the following function.

```
// Display cart item custom data in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_custom_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_item_custom_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label0']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value0']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label0'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value0'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value'],
        );
    }

    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label2']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value2']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label2'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value2'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label3']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value3']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label3'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value3'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label4']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value4']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label4'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value4'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label5']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value5']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label5'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value5'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label6']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value6']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label6'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value6'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label7']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value7']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label7'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value7'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label8']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value8']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label8'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value8'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label9']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value9']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label9'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value9'],
        );
    }
    
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label10']) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value10']) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label10'],
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value10'],
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

This works and the custom data is shown in the cart. However, the custom data does not show on the order and order email. I have seen, on Stackoverflow several answers that provide solutions to this problem but I cannot make them work for my situation. The solutions that I reference are.

[Save and display order item custom meta data in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687705/save-and-display-order-item-custom-meta-data-in-woocommerce)

[Display and save added custom cart item data on Woocommerce Cart, Checkout and Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505642/display-and-save-added-custom-cart-item-data-on-woocommerce-cart-checkout-and-o)

Can anybody kindly show me what "my" function should be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can optimize and compact your function this way:

```
// Display cart item custom data in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_custom_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_item_custom_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    $keys = array('0','','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'); // Fields numbers part keys array
    
    // Loop through Fields numbers part keys array
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['label'.$key]) && isset($cart_item['custom_data']['value'.$key]) ) {
            $cart_item_data[] = array(
                'name' => $cart_item['custom_data']['label'.$key],
                'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['value'.$key],
            );
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Then to save all your custom cart item data as custom order item meta data and display it everywhere on orders and emails, use the following:

```
// Save cart item custom data as order item meta data and display it everywhere in Orders and email notifications
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_as_custom_order_item_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_as_custom_order_item_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $keys = array('0','','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'); // Fields numbers part keys array()
    
    // Loop through Fields numbers part keys array
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if( isset( $values['custom_data']['label'.$key] ) && isset( $values['custom_data']['value'.$key] ) ) {
           $item->update_meta_data( $values['custom_data']['label'.$key], $values['custom_data']['value'.$key] );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Excellent! Works. Thank you!